# When and why to use [:] in python

Tags: python, syntax

```
sentence = "Hello"
print sentence
print sentence[:]
```

Both outputs the same thing, i.e. `Hello`

So, when and why to use/not use `[:]` ?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Get information about that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation

Comment: No effort from your side, it seems you didn't even research what this does.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I'm really sorry... but this is my first post in stackoverflow... and i don't know it's called the slicing notation, i did have problem searching for [:] in google search. :)

Answer (score 8):

As [Nobi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3449019/nobi) pointed out in the comments, there's already a [question regarding Python's slicing notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation). As stated in the answer to that question, the slicing without start and end values (`[:]`) basically creates a copy of the original sequence.

However, you have hit a special case with strings. Since strings are immutable, it makes no sense to create a copy of a string. Since you won't be able to modify any instance of the string, there's no need to have more than one in memory. So, basically, with `s[:]` (being `s` a string) you're not creating a copy of the string; that statement is returning the very same string referenced by `s`. An easy way to see this is by using the `id()` (object identity) function:

```
>>> l1 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> l2 = l1[:]
>>> id(l1)
3075103852L
>>> id(l2)
3072580172L
```

Identities are different. However, with strings:

```
>>> s1 = "Hello"
>>> s2 = s1[:]
>>> id(s1)
3072585984L
>>> id(s2)
3072585984L
```

Identity is the same, meaning both are the same exact object.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b=a[:]
>>> id(b)
4387312200
>>> id(a)
4387379464
```

When you want to make a deep copy of an array.

```
>>> a='123'
>>> b=a[:]
>>> id(a)
4387372528
>>> id(b)
4387372528
```

But since string is immutable, string[:] has no difference with string itself.

P.S. I see most of people answering this question didn't understand what is  the question at all.

Comment: This makes a *shallow* copy of the list, not a deep copy. You can confirm this by noticing that `a = [[]]`; b = a[:]; a[0] is b[0]` gives True. To do a true deep copy, use `copy.deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy).

Comment: ... no, no they don't. `a = []; b = []; a is b` is False. And conversely, you can put whatever you want into the inner list and get the same result - `mylist[:]` does *not* make copies of any of the objects in the list. Try `a = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]; b = a[:]; print(a[0] is b[0]); a[0].append('e'); print(b[0])`.

Answer (score 0):

Thee reason why you are getting Hello as output, is you are not passing any parameter.

```
L[start:stop:step]
```

Here L is your variable, which holds Hello. and start means the initial position of the string and stop means where you want to end your string with & step means how many char you want to skip.

For more information on this topic, visit [this](http://effbot.org/zone/python-list.htm)

See, if that resolved your issue.